# Why are the file permissions that are set using Golang different than expected?

Tags: string, file, go, permissions, int

```
func stringToInt(s string) int {
    i, err := strconv.Atoi(s)
    check(err)
    return i
}

os.FileMode(stringToInt("0777"))
```

when no conversion to int is required (leading zero is not removed) by setting the permission directly:

```
os.FileMode(0777)
```

the file permissions are correct

**Current outcome**

```
777
777
-r----x--x
753
753
--wxrw---x
500
500
-rwxrw-r--
```

**Expected outcome**

```
777
-rwxrwxrwx
753
-r-xr-x-wx
500
-r-x------
```

Comment: Is the problem that you're expecting `"0777"` to be interpreted as octal?

Comment: The only context in which `0777` is different than `777` is as a string. If you're converting it to `int` then of course it loses its leading digit. As @JamesHenstridge asked: do you expect `0777` to be `777 base 8`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments of @AdamSmith and @JamesHenstridge the following solves the issue:

```
mode, _ := strconv.ParseInt(fileAttributes["mode"], 8, 32)

0777
511
-rwxrwxrwx
0753
491
-r-xr-x-wx
0500
320
-r-x------
```

However when the leading zeros have been removed the outcome is exactly the same:

```
777
511
-rwxrwxrwx
753
491
-r-xr-x-wx
500
320
-r-x------
```

In conclusion, the leading zeros are not required at all. It was the incorrect type that was causing the issue.